# Golang: code duplication and similar structs

Tags: go

What's an idiomatic way in Go to superclass similar (but not identical) data types in order to minimize code duplication?  Trite example:

```
import "time"

type LinuxUtmp struct {
    ut_type uint16
    _       [2]byte
    ut_pid  uint32
    ut_line [32]byte
    ut_id   [4]byte
    ut_user [32]byte
    ut_host [256]byte
    exit_status [2]uint32
    tv_sec  uint32
    tv_usec uint32
    ...
}

func (l LinuxUtmp) User() string {
    return string(l.ut_user[:])
}

func (l LinuxUtmp) Time() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(int64(l.tv_sec), int64(l.tv_usec))
}

type BsdUtmp struct {
    ut_line [8]char
    ut_name [16]char
    ut_host [16]char
    ut_time uint32
}

func (b BsdUtmp) User() string {
    return string(b.ut_user[:])
}

func (b BsdUtmp) Time() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(int64(b.ut_time), 0)
}
```

Obviously there's more to it than that, but I'd love to be able to somehow superclass those so I only have to write and maintain one copy of particular functions.  An interface seems to be the "right" way, but that leaves much to be desired (non-working example):

```
type Utmp interface {
    Time() time.Time
}

func User(u Utmp) string {
    return string(u.ut_user[:])
}
```

I've also considered embedding, but that seems a dead end too since Go is so strictly typed.  Am I doomed to have multiple pieces of code that are identical in every way but the signature?

[edit]

Part of the complication is that I'm using encoding/binary.Read() to parse this data according to endianness (it's not just utmp records and not just Linux/BSD).  To use that, the fields must be [exported] in the struct in the precise order they are on-disk.  Hence I can't just embed the fields of another struct, as in some records they're in different order (and of differing sizes)

Comment: What makes embedding insufficient? Whatever superclass functionality you want, you should be able to implement without duplication by defining a type that has a common subset of fields, putting the methods that deal with them there and then embedding it in the types that would inherit in a subclass-superclass relationship. While the relationship between the types is inverted, there is afaik, nothing preventing the same exact functionality with embedding.

Comment: See the clarification edit and/or my response to Darkstar for why embedding isn't going to fulfill what I need.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your comment about embedding. Here is how I'd do it (using embedding):

```golang
package test

import "time"

type Utmp struct {
    // Common fields
}

func (u Utmp) User() {
    return string(l.ut_user[:])
}

type LinuxUtmp struct {
    Utmp
    // Linux specific fields
}

func (l LinuxUtmp) Time() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(int64(l.tv_sec), int64(l.tv_usec))
}

type BsdUtmp struct {
    Utmp
    // BSD specific fields
}

func (b BsdUtmp) Time() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(int64(b.ut_time), 0)
}
```

Any code importing the library can call `User()` method directly on `LinuxUtmp` and `BsdUtmp` objects directly as `l.User()` or `b.User()` without mentioning `Utmp` at all. You can even keep `Utmp` unexpected (as `utmp`) if you like.

Check out [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) for details.

You can even ensure that only the code meant for the relevant platform gets compiled in the binary, if you like. [This blog](http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-conditional-compilation/) has got some examples. In the interest of keeping things simple, I wouldn't bother going down that route if the platform specific code is not very big or there are other factors involved.

For the sake of completeness, here is the official [go build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) doc.

Comment: The "rest" of the story (and also in partial answer to @evanmcdonnal )is that I'm using encoding/binary.Read(...) to parse these structs from a buffer.  They have to be in the struct in precisely the order they are on-disk.  As this practice will feed to other structures and endianness, I'd really rather not reimplement that function, but suppose I could copy data once read.  Not sure which is the greater evil - gratuitous data copying or excessively duplicated code.

Comment: @user5429110: Edited after reading your response more closely. You can read the data in a buffer struct that matches the format you need and copy the fields to the final structs. In case your application is very performance sensitive and can't tolerate the overhead of copying, you could have the final structs hold references to the actual data read in the buffer instead of copying. Since Go uses automatic GC, you don't need to worry about the memory management issues an approach like this would gave caused.

Comment: Good point; I'll check that out.  I don't expect this code to be too terribly performance critical, but people rarely do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem that the types of some things are different, you could make the `Time` and `User` functions operate on an interface that wraps linux and bsd functionality.

If you don't like that, you can generate the code to avoid duplication.

Comment: I thought that's what my last example was attempting to do, unless you mean a "nested" interface.

Comment: Yes, I mean having two interfaces.